# Fetch: how to deal with a json payload in an error response?

Tags: javascript, promise

Trying to get https://github.com/github/fetch working with an API that almost always returns a json payload, even when the response is an error:

```
{
  "message": "User not logged in",
  "code": 401
}
```

So I came up with this, adopting [their status check example](https://github.com/github/fetch#handling-http-error-statuses)

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
  } else {
    return response.json()
      .catch(() => {
        var error = new Error(response.statusText)
        error.response = response
        throw error
      }).then((json) => {
        var error = new Error(json.message || response.statusText)
        error.response = response
        throw error
      });
  }
}
```

This would handle both json and an invalid json reponse in case the api isn't able to produce valid json.

Would this be okay or am I missing something? I don't really like the `.catch` before the `.then`, but otherwise the `.catch` will catch the thrown error.. which is not what we want..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note this reads more like a hypothetical question but I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt.

Your example is alright, but it has a few issues. I'm going to mostly touch on semantics here, so bear with me. Note I'll be going with the WHATWG spec that's implemented in browsers now, which should be the same as the repo you've linked, but just so you are aware :)

```
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
```

There's no need to check `response.status` like this; it also doesn't cover all "success" responses (assuming that is indeed what you're trying to do. WHATWG `fetch` exposes an `ok` property on the response object which will do this for you..

```
  if (response.ok) {
    return response
```

Let's look at your function as a whole.

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

As this is just a straight up `if-else`, you can reduce cyclomatic complexity by dropping the `else` here.

```
  return response.json()
    .catch(() => {
      var error = new Error(response.statusText)
      error.response = response
      throw error
    }).then((json) => {
      var error = new Error(json.message || response.statusText)
      error.response = response
      throw error
    });
```

I think this is a bit redundant. I'm guessing what you're trying to do is either:

1. Catch, and re-throw (thus rejecting the promise), the error with the `response` property if you hit this branch if there was already an exception
2. Reject the promise by throwing an error if there was not an exception by taking the response json and assigning it as an error message.

I'd argue that you *should not* be catching the error in the first place. The only place an error will occur here is if there is a JSON syntax error. There's nothing you can do to handle this, so don't attach bits and pieces to it; the only thing it would be useful for is debugging, and you shouldn't be adding debugging stuff like this to the user's browser - this should be caught in e2e tests. Instead, just let the default error propagate up. This leaves you with this so far:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response
  }
  return response.json().then((json) => {
    var error = new Error(json.message || response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  });
}
```

The next thing I have to add is this function could either be synchronous or asynchronous depending on what is passed to it. This is a bad thing and [is explained here](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) by more clever people than I. The upshot is that you should design your API so that if it can return asynchronously, it always should. Solution to this is just to wrap `response` in a `Promise.resolve()`.

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  }

  return response.json().then((json) => {
    var error = new Error(json.message || response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  });
}
```

Next:

1. Your semi colons aren't consistent. Either use them or don't. Don't mix and match, it just confuses everyone.
2. If you're using ES6 arrows, you can use `const`/`let` as well. Use them.

You could simplify your promise handler code by using something like `Object.assign` if you support it or `_.assign` otherwise, which makes things nice and sugary.

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  }

  return response.json().then(json => {
    const error = new Error(json.message || response.statusText)
    throw Object.assign(error, { response })
  })
}
```

Consider using `Promise.reject` instead of `throw`. It's a standard API for promises and clearly communicates your intent. Unwinding the stack trace isn't fun.

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  }

  return response.json().then(json => {
    const error = new Error(json.message || response.statusText)
    return Promise.reject(Object.assign(error, { response }))
  })
}
```

I think that's about it for now. I think it's weird you're doing either `json.message || response.statusText` as an error message, but whatever floats your boat. Error reporting messages are largely what is helpful to the developer. I'd recommend you put user-friendly error message handling *somewhere*, though.

Comment: Wow, this is way more then I hoped to get out of this code review. Thanks a lot for taking so much time for my question. To give you some background info. The inconsistencies slipped in because I first wanted to add this as a PR to their repo but hesitated because I was doubting the code too much and did not want to more of a question then a PR. I then created a question on StackOverflow, but realized it might be better to add it here. The snippet I used in my project was using semicolons and let/const.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on mixed returns. I hadn't realized that yet, good point. About catching the error, if you don't catch it if parsing the json fails, then you won't be able to do something with the `response.statusText` right? So the displayed message to the user would be something like: 'Unexpected token x' instead of 'Internal server error'. You're right, unwinding the stack trace is indeed no fun, I wonder why the fetch repo is throwing the error directly, maybe they don't want to include any Promises in the docs..

Comment: About the `json.message || response.statusText`. That was done to either get the user friendly message from the json payload, or, if it was not provided, fall back to the `statusText`, that is the most user friendly we can do right? Well you could hardcode a 'Sorry data could not be loaded' message in your javascript of course.. maybe that would be better indeed.

Comment: Don't had code if, I just wouldn't use that in an `Error` object, personally

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? You mean that you wouldn't send the error message along with the api response?

Comment: I mean I wouldn't use `Error` to hold a user response ^^

Comment: Well I only used error because that is wat the example threw in the first place. What would an alternative be, use a plain js object with a `msg` and a `response` key to hold the original response?

Comment: http://2ality.com/2016/03/promise-rejections-vs-exceptions.html Use this https://medium.com/@luminarious/i-was-trying-out-fetch-literally-this-morning-and-i-notice-you-kind-of-skipped-a-simple-solution-62a734c28dfb